# FontAwesome character added via CSS only appears when logged in

Tags: users, theming

I'm pretty new to Drupal and CSS; I'm stumped with this issue. I have a FontAwesome camera character that I've written to appear before my caption div in Flexslider. Here's what I have:

```
div.flex-caption:before {
    content: "\f083";
    font-family: fontawesome;
    margin-left:10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

This works fine when I'm logged in as a user to the site, but the icon doesn't appear if I'm not logged in to my Drupal site. Not sure why—any ideas? I'm using Drupal 7.31

Edit: Just to clarify, all other FontAwesome characters are working fine. It's just this particular bit of code that isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your CSS rule is in the CSS for your administrative theme (by default "Seven"), but not in the theme for your public (non-logged-in) users (by default "Bartik")?

If so, you need to copy this CSS fragment into the public theme too.

Comment: I should have been more clear in my question, so apologies for that—I'm only a site administrator working on the local site of a bigger organization. The main CSS and theme info is 'locked' for us and we cannot access it; but we are allowed to make local CSS changes using the Sweaver module. As far as I can tell, all of the Sweaver CSS additions have affected the public theme as you can see them regardless of whether you're logged in. Only this FontAwesome character has been a problem. Let me know if you need more clarification on that